# Где найти подлинный грамматический словарь Зализняка?

Tags: грамматика

Вопросы следующие:

1) **Есть ли такой адрес в Интернете,** которому можно доверять? (Наверное, должен быть).

2) **Какие сайты** имеют возможность (**официальное разрешение)**  копировать материалы и почему они это делают с ошибками?

2) Зализняк делал словарь вручную для первых 100 тыс. слов. **А насколько точны модели словоизменения**, которые были выполнены уже компьютерными программами? **Могут ли быть ошибки и в них?**

[http://wikiredia.ru/wiki/Андрей_Анатольевич_Зализняк](http://wikiredia.ru/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA)

Продолжением идеологии «Русского именного словоизменения» стал классический «Грамматический словарь русского языка» (1977, 4-е изд. 2003[18]), **где для 100 тыс. слов русского языка указана точная модель словоизменения (и предложена классификация самих этих моделей). Словарь, составленный А. А. Зализняком вручную, стал основой практически для всех компьютерных программ** автоматического морфологического анализа (в том числе в информационном поиске, в машинном переводе и т. п.)

Comment: Есть еще один адрес. Вечером постараюсь дать ссылку. Сейчас пишу с т/ф, не могу.

Comment: https://udarenieru.ru/index.php

Comment: @ Серж Спасибо за ссылку, но у меня ничего не получается. По ссылке открывается страница, на которой написано, что на сайте есть грамматический и морфемный словари, дается их краткое описание. Но где их искать - непонятно.

Comment: @ Sharon, в строке поиск введите слово. А там уже все сами поймете.

Answer (score 2):

Вот по **[этой ссылке](https://freedocs.xyz/djvu-456354246)** его (якобы) можно скачать и просто посмотреть - я не пробовала (не поняла, на что/куда смотреть).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ещё такое предложение на сайте ODict.ru, где строчки кликабельны:

[ОТКРЫТЫЙ ГРАММАТИЧЕСКИЙ СЛОВАРЬ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА](http://odict.ru/)

> oDict.ru – это открытый словарь русского языка, основанный на
>   «Грамматическом словаре» А. А. Зализняка. «Открытый» означает, что он
>   доступен для скачивания бесплатно и что любой желающий может его
>   пополнять и редактировать.
>
> Пополнить словарь
>
> Скачать словарь, 735K
>
> Скачать словарь словоформ, 7М
>
> Формат словаря — текстовый файл в кодировке Windows-1251 в архиве ZIP.
>   Версии для скачивания обновляются с интервалом около 5 минут.

И ещё, на просьбу а покажь онлайн, слабо? мне и отвечают:

**[Грамматический словарь Зализняка](https://gufo.me/dict/zaliznyak)**

> Грамматический словарь русского языка (словарь Зализняка) —
>   составленный А. А. Зализняком словарь содержит приблизительно 100 тыс.
>   слов русского языка с их полным морфологическим описанием.
>   Основополагающий труд по морфологии, где впервые был предложен
>   системный подход к описанию грамматических парадигм, включающих не
>   только изменение буквенного состава слов, но и ударения.

На страничке - буковки алфавита, гляди что хошь.

Comment: Спасибо, мне хотелось бы не скачать книгу, а иметь ссылку на надежный источник. Потом это 100 тыс. слов, а часто говорят о полной парадигме. В общем, полная парадигма, что-то вроде  "со знаком проверено, ошибок нет" (РАН),  Можно доверять, как самому себе.

Answer (score 0):

**Официальный сайт словаря: [gramdict.ru](http://gramdict.ru)**

Сайт соответствует шестому изданию словаря и включает приложение с именами собственными.

Сайт gramdict.ru создан с разрешения правообладателя словаря на основе версии, полученной непосредственно от правообладателя. Насколько мне известно со слов правообладателя, с которым я лично знаком, никакие другие сайты не имеют разрешения воспроизводить текст словаря, за исключением сайтов издательства «АСТ-Пресс».

На Ваш третий вопрос у меня нет точного ответа - все ошибки на совести авторов новых словарных статей и программ генерации словоформ по индексу.